# C# WebClient freezes after a certain time in a while(true) loop

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I'm working on my Grade Project and run into this issue.
I'm making a control panel for a parking lot and I use Arduino for reading the sensors and WebServer that sends the values of the sensors in a JSON file to a connected client.

I've made a C# form that indicates if there is a car parked on spot 1,2,... etc.
So, I designed a little form that does this, it contains a second threat that runs an infinite loop which creates a WebClient that will collect the JSON from the Arduino WebServer and when done the JSON will be handled and the spots are being indicated.

After a few seconds, the thread freezes, more specific the WebClient that is opening the read just freezes.
I've spent a few days now to find out how to fix this issue, no success yet.
So I tried to make another thread that checks if the connection started and it takes more than a second to get the data it will try to abort the thread of the WebClient and creating a new one, to resume getting the JSON I thought.

But when the Timer hits a second the thread that tries to abort the other threat also freezes.

I gave up and decided to ask it on StackOverflow because I can't find a solution.

this is my thread for the WebClient:

```
private void startConnectionThread()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://192.168.0.177/");
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                    strResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    data.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                    handleResult(strResult);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

I can use all your help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
This is my method with HttpClient the same issue but after a few seconds the freezing connection refreshes and it works again, I see this as a solution to my problem. And when I add `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);` it does abridge the time out.

```
private void startConnectionThread()
    {
        new Thread(async() =>
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.177/");
                    strResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    handleResult(strResult);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }).Start();
    }
```

Comment: You should create the WebClient instance once and use the same instance.

Comment: We had a similar issue with HttpClient. HttpClient was not getting disposed even when we called the dispose method. We then created the HttpClient once and reused it every time it was needed. You could try that with WebClient.

Comment: @NachiappanKumarappan You shouldn't call Dispose on an HttpClient anyways.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try that!

Comment: Either have the catch block do something - such as log errors, or get rid of it. It's just going to hide errors if you leave it as is.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8 `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.`

Comment: I realize you are using the older WebClient instead of the newer recommended HttpClient, but I suspect the underlying issue may be the same or similar.

Comment: @RobertMcKee how do I check if this exception occurred? My try/catches don't catch such exception

Comment: Your try/catch should catch it, but looks like you aren't doing anything in the exception handler.  It is also possible that while HttpClient will throw the SocketException, WebClient may just block for a considerable time (5-15 minutes) until a socket becomes available.

Comment: I see I'll implement the HttpClient instead and see where that brings me.

Comment: It's also possible that whatever you are connecting to is misbehaving as well, and not closing the connection.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I do close the connection (server-sided) .

Comment: @Robert also HttpClient stays freezing my thread

Comment: although it takes much longer now until it freezes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same `WebClient` instance, not recreate it in the loop as the other previously created clients are still in use, taking up connections and listening.

So move it out of your loop...

```
 var client = new WebClient();     

 while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var data = client.OpenRead("http://192.168.0.177/"))
                {                
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                        strResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        handleResult(strResult);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: You may also want to do something with your exception in the catch block. Even if it's just write it to a label on the form so you can see why something is going wrong, rather than fail silently

Comment: This did not work, it still randomly freezes after a few seconds. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: And I'm doing the catch in a message box but it doesn't pop up when it freezes so I assume there is no exception.

Comment: this is an example of the JSON : https://pastebin.com/1HsiePym

Comment: Hmm so hardly any, it could be an issue on the side you're getting the data from, it may be worth putting `reader.ReadToEnd` into the form to see if anything is coming back.

Comment: The first few seconds I receive this JSON and I can handle it in my form it's just after  10 seconds or so the WebClient just freezes the thread completely.

Comment: what does handleResult() do? Anything that could cause the thread to pause?

Comment: it just handles the JSON and set form controls in this case picture boxes to true and false, but even when setting the function call as a comment it still freezes

Comment: Strange, I noticed yout StreamReader is closed() manually. You may want to amend this so that it is in a using statement.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The problem is still there. But it seems HttpClient "solves" the problem with a change to the TimeOut property. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your time and effort. I do appreciate it!

Comment: You might want to pull the HandleResult and Thread.Sleep out of the using statements so that those resources can be disposed of a little bit quicker.  Otherwise, and excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution for me, using HttpClient and the change in the timeout property did make the change.

```
private void startConnectionThread()
{
    new Thread(async() =>
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.177/");
                strResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                handleResult(strResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }).Start();
}
```